# WPF list available printers and trays

Tags: wpf, printers, tray

I'm writing WPF application which needs to display list of available Printers and corresponding trays.

I can able to get list of available printers by loop through the following line

**PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters**

and now stuck up with getting corresponding printer trays. 
could anybody give sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `PaperSources` property - `Gets the paper source trays that are available on the printer`. (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
    using System.Printing
    ......

    var printers = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueues().Select(v => v.Name);
```